# How do I convert this array of arrays into nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have the data in this nested array format that i am reading from a csv.

```js
const data = [[P1,A1,W1],[P1,A1,W2],[P1,A1,W3],
              [P1,A2,W4],[P1,A2,W5],[P1,A2,W6],
              [P2,A3,W7],[P2,A3,W8],[P2,A3,W9]]
```

I'm trying to convert this data into this format -

```js
   
[
            {
                text:P1,
                sub_list:[
                    {
                        text:A1,
                        sub_list:[
                            {
                                text:W1,
                                sub_list:[]
                            },
                            {
                                text:W2,
                                sub_list:[]
                            },
                            {
                                text:W3,
                                sub_list:[]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                      {
                        text:A2,
                        sub_list:[
                            {
                                text:W4,
                                sub_list:[]
                            },
                            {
                                text:W5,
                                sub_list:[]
                            },
                            {
                                text:W6,
                                sub_list:[]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text:P2,
                sub_list:[
                    {
                        text:A3,
                        sub_list:[
                            {
                                text:W7,
                                sub_list:[]
                            },
                            {
                                text:W8,
                                sub_list:[]
                            },
                            {
                                text:W9,
                                sub_list:[]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I'm unable to figure out a working solution.
I'm thinking to do this in a recursive way.
The no. of items in the nested array can be more than 3.

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is here to help you with specific issues you have with code _you've written_. You should make an attempt at a solution first, and then come back if you have any problems with it adding the code to the question as a [mcve] even if it doesn't work, and then we can help debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  ['P1', 'A1', 'W1'],
  ['P1', 'A1', 'W2'],
  ['P1', 'A1', 'W3'],
  ['P1', 'A2', 'W4'],
  ['P1', 'A2', 'W5'],
  ['P1', 'A2', 'W6'],
  ['P2', 'A3', 'W7'],
  ['P2', 'A3', 'W8'],
  ['P2', 'A3', 'W9']
]

const obj = []

for (const item of data) {
  let current = obj
  for (const sub of item) {
    const subItem = current.find(i => i.text === sub)
    if (subItem) {
      current = subItem.sub_list
    } else {
      const newItem = {
        sub_list: [],
        text: sub
      }
      current.push(newItem)
      current = newItem.sub_list
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a map to know from a (partial) path which is the corresponding object in the target hierarchy (in case it is already present there). While you follow a path you can lookup the parent node via that map and insert the child into its "sublist".

Here is a function that does that:

```js
function hierarchy(data) {
    const root = [];
    const map = { "": root };
    for (const path of data) {
        let key = "";
        for (const text of path) {
            let parent = key;
            key += "\n" + text;
            if (!(key in map)) {
                map[parent].push({text, sublist: map[key] = []});
            }
        }
    }
    return root;
}

const data = [['P1', 'A1', 'W1'],['P1', 'A1', 'W2'],['P1', 'A1', 'W3'],['P1', 'A2', 'W4'],['P1', 'A2', 'W5'],['P1', 'A2', 'W6'],['P2', 'A3', 'W7'],['P2', 'A3', 'W8'],['P2', 'A3', 'W9']];
const arr = hierarchy(data);
console.log(arr);
```